# Try/Catch is breaking Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Functions and have a try / catch within a get().then( ... ) function.

ESLint is calling the catch an error with:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token { eslint

If I get rid of the try/catch completely, the error rolls up to another issue which is:

```
Each then() should return a value or throw eslint(promise/always-return)
```

That error resolves when adding

```
return null
```

I tried adding return null to the code when the try/catch was there to see if the issue may have just been that it was missing it, but it doesn't fix it.

An example of what this actually looks like in the code is this, I have tried what seems like everything:
[image]

Comment: syntax is incorrect. It should be  `catch() {}`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Please don't show images of code.  Copy the code into the question itself and format it, so that it's easy to read and search.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change

```
try {...}
catch {...}
```

to

```
try {...}
catch(e) {...}
```